# Is CallbackContract a good strategy for one-to-one communication?

Tags: c#, wcf

### The Background

I have a WCF client and service with a one-to-one relationship (i.e. one service host per client).    I use a callback contract to pass messages from the service to the client.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageTarget)]
public interface IMessageService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void StartMessages();
}

public interface IMessageTarget
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task SendAsync(Message message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Complete();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Fault(ExceptionDetail exception);
}
```

On the client, I set up a duplex connection to begin communication.  `MessageTarget.Completion` completes when the `Complete()` or `Fault(ExceptionDetail)` methods are called.

```
IMessageTarget target = new MessageTarget();
var channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessageService>(target, new NetNamedPipeBinding());
IMessageService service = channelFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(EndpointUri));

service.StartMessages();
await target.Completion;
```

The service sends messages to the client as soon as they become available.  The client is able to delay further messages by making `SendAsync()` take a long time to return.

```
IMessageTarget client = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageTarget>();

// later, whenever a message is created
await client.SendAsync(message);

// finally
client.Complete();
```

### The Problem

I discovered that the client hangs if the service crashes.  Unfortunately, WCF provides no reliable way to detect if the service is still up, other than calling a service method and catching `CommunicationException`.  Therefore, I added a new operation

```
[OperationContract]
Task PingAsync();
```

so the client can monitor if the service goes down.

```
service.StartMessages();
while (!target.Completion.IsCompleted)
{
    await service.PingAsync();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
}
await target.Completion;
```

### The Question

Doesn't this defeat the purpose of using callbacks?  I'm struggling to see how this "listen for callbacks while constantly pinging" strategy is better than simply polling for the latest messages (with no duplex required).  Did I over-engineer this, or is there some other benefit to callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most WCF related exceptions are derived from [CommunicationsException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationexception(v=vs.110).aspx), so what you did is good in that sense. As you noted, pinging / polling defeats the purpose of the callback implementation. Bottom line, you need to just call the service and be ready to deal with any exceptions that happen during the service invocation. There's really no reliable way to see if the service is available.

If you are not already doing so, you can also look at the [IClientChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.iclientchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) events to monitor what happens with the connection.

```
client.InnerChannel.Closed += OnChannelClosed;
client.InnerChannel.Opening += OnChannelOpening;
client.InnerChannel.Opened += OnChannelOpened;
client.InnerChannel.Closing += OnChannelClosing;
client.InnerChannel.Faulted += OnChannelFaulted;
client.InnerChannel.UnknownMessageReceived += OnChannelUnknownMessageReceived;
```

Comment: I tried subscribing to `((ICommunicationObject)service).Closed`, but it does not get fired if the service process dies.  On the upside, this research has led me to a better understanding of [half-open connections](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).

Comment: @piedar What about Faulted?

Comment: Oh wow, `Faulted` does fire after all.  It makes my question moot, but I am glad I don't need to Ping().